# Calculating trajectory of particle moving in a potential (SHM)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I have been given the potential of a simple harmonic oscillator:

$$V=\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}$$

I want to calculate the value $x(t)$ of a particle moving in this potential, with initial conditions $x(t=0)=0$ and $v(t=0)=v_{0}$. How would I go about doing this in simple classical mechanics?

Should I be using Hooke's law and Newton's second Law to create a second order differential equation, and solve? Any guidance or hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting the equation**

1. *Using Newton's second law:*

$$
ma_x \equiv m\ddot{x}=F_x=-\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}=-kx
$$

$$
\ddot{x}+\frac{k}{m}x=0
$$

2. *Using lagrangian formulation:*

$$
L=T-V=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2-\frac{1}{2}kx^2
$$

then:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(\frac{\mathrm{\partial}L}{\mathrm{\partial}\dot{x}}\right)- \frac{\mathrm{\partial}L}{\mathrm{\partial}x}=m\ddot{x}+kx=0
$$

3. *Using hamiltonian formulation:*

$$
H=T+V=\frac{p_x^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}kx^2
$$

and then from Hamilton's equations:

$$
kx=-\dot{p_x} \ \ , \ \ \frac{p_x}{m} = \dot{x}
$$

then apply derivative with respect to time to the second equation and sum both of them.

**Solving the equation:**

You can guess the solution $x = A\cos \sqrt{k/m}t+B\sin \sqrt{k/m}t$ or you can use substitution $x=e^{\lambda t}$ and find $\lambda$.

Anyway:

$$
x(t=0) = A\cos 0 + B\sin 0 = A = 0
$$

$$
v(t=0) = -A\sqrt{k/m}\sin 0 + B\sqrt{k/m}\cos 0 = B\sqrt{k/m} = v_0
$$

therefore:

$$
x(t)=\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}v_0\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

With given potential you can define force acting on your oscillator as $$F = - \dfrac{dV}{dx} = -kx$$
This gives you Hooks law (no surprise). Than just use Newton's second law:
$$ma = -kx$$
Than create second order differential equation replacing $a$ with $\ddot{x}$ and solve it with your initial conditions.